# How can I open the Python Console as a different window or a widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I have created a program that uses Tkinter and it asks for the user's inputs in the Python Shell. I would like to make it so the user's inputs are written in a separate window or a widget of the Python Console. Is this possible to do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not really sure what you want, do you already have a Tkinter Window or do you have  a console program? Do you want the input to take place in the console or in the Tkinter window? If you want an input field in a Tkinter window you should use a `tkinter.Entry`

Comment: @Tom I already have a Tkinter window but the inputs are taken in the Python console, but I want to be able to make the Python console appear as a customised widget or nest the Python console inside of Tkinter

Comment: This isn't that easy I think, you can have a look at https://github.com/Saadmairaj/tkterminal, but it only provides a terminal widget, not specifically a python console. But why would you do that? The whole reason of creating a Tkinter UI is to get rid of console based input and output. Maybe you could use an Entry or a TextBox and pass the input to the python console yourself with os.system and then display the output.

Comment: @Tom I had already created parts of my program prior to this knowledge and then my teacher mentioned it to me. I wasn't too sure about all the features with Tkinter, but 100% the tkinter.Entry would have been much easier to do but due to the time limit I have, I'm not 100% sure I will be able to do it again with just Entry or a TextBox. I will remember these functions in the future though! Many thanks for your help and the link.